# Fastest way to compare combination of values in two columns through Array (or any other suitable option) in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have hundreds of Group of Items in Column 1. For ex; Group A, Group B, Group C and so on.
Each Item, in each Group corresponds to 'TRUE' or 'FALSE' in Column 2.

1. A Group evaluates to 'TRUE' if all the items in that group correspond to 'TRUE'.
2. A Group evaluates to 'FALSE' if any or all of the items correspond to 'FALSE'.
3. A Group can have a single item that correspond to 'TRUE' or 'FALSE'.

I can explain it better with an example.

**Example:**

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | TRUE |
| A | TRUE |
| A | FALSE |
| B | TRUE |
| C | FALSE |
| D | FALSE |
| D | TRUE |
| E | TRUE |
| E | TRUE |
| E | TRUE |
| F | FALSE |
| G | TRUE |
| G | TRUE |

*What am I trying to achieve:*

1. Intention is to retain only those Groups that evaluate to 'TRUE' value. So, basically final result would look something like:

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| B | TRUE |
| E | TRUE |
| E | TRUE |
| E | TRUE |
| G | TRUE |
| G | TRUE |

2. To perform some sort of action with Groups that evaluate to False, For ex; Delete entire Group (rows) from the sheet.

---

Can someone point me in the right direction as to how can I achieve this with VBA. Any help would be highly appreciated. (Apologies for my not so great explanation skills. I am trying to improve)

Comment: Do you simple need to delete the rows keeping `FALSE` in column B:B? Or keep the groups having **all** values `TRUE`?

Comment: I would like to delete entire rows for a group that evaluates to False. For ex: Row 1-3. Because group A has two True and one False so the whole group will evaluate to False

Comment: Sorry, I missed another part of your question. You are right. I wish to keep only those groups that have all values as 'TRUE'.

Comment: OK. I will prepare an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next code. It assumes that the two columns in discussion are A:A and B:B. It does not delete the rows (to be deleted), now. It only selects them. If the code returns as you need, please change `Select` with `Delete` on the code line before the final message:

```
Sub TestTRUEGroups()
  'it needs a reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime'
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, i As Long, dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
  Dim arr, arrDel, El, arrD, rngDel As Range, strRng As String, k As Long, chk, j As Long
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet                     'use here the sheet you need
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last filled row in column A:A
  arr = sh.Range("A1:B" & lastR).value     'put the range in an array, to make the iteration faster
  ReDim arrDel(1 To UBound(arr)): k = 1 'Redim the array to keep the group names to be deleted
  
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr)        'iterate between the array elements
        If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 1)) Then
            dict.Add arr(i, 1), i 'create a new key in the dictionary, with a value of the group element row
            If arr(i, 2) = "FALSE" Then arrDel(k) = arr(i, 1): k = k + 1 'place the group in the array to delete them
        Else
            dict(arr(i, 1)) = dict(arr(i, 1)) & "," & i     'add the row number of the next occurrence
            chk = Application.match(arr(i, 1), arrDel, 0)   'check if the group is already in the array
            If IsError(chk) And arr(i, 2) = "FALSE" Then arrDel(k) = arr(i, 1): k = k + 1 'put it in the array acc. to conditions
        End If
  Next i

  ReDim Preserve arrDel(1 To k - 1) 'keep only the array elements having values
  For i = 0 To dict.count - 1       'iterate btween dictionary elements
        For Each El In arrDel
            If El = dict.Keys(i) Then            'if the dict key is found
                arrD = Split(dict.items(i), ",") 'put its content in an array
                For j = 0 To UBound(arrD)
                    strRng = strRng & "A" & arrD(j) & "," 'make a string of addresses (Adding A)
                Next j
                strRng = left(strRng, Len(strRng) - 1)    'remove the final comma
                If rngDel Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngDel = sh.Range(strRng)         'create the range to be deleted
                Else
                    Set rngDel = Union(rngDel, sh.Range(strRng)) 'make a Union with the previous range
                End If
                strRng = "": Exit For 'reinitialize strRng and exit the For Next loop
            End If
       Next
  Next i
  If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Select 'if it returns correctly, change Select with Delete
  MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

Attention: The code runs for a range starting from the first row (as in your example). If you want putting some headers or start from another row (when building the array), then you should add the difference when memorize rows (`dict.Add arr(i, 1), i + NrRows`).

If adding a reference looks difficult, please run the next code to add it automatically (before running the above one):

```
Sub addScrRunTimeRef()
  'Add a reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime':
  'In case of error ('Programmatic access to Visual Basic Project not trusted'):
  'Options->Trust Center->Trust Center Settings->Macro Settings->Developer Macro Settings->
  '         check "Trust access to the VBA project object model"
  Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll"
End Sub
```

It is good to save the workbook in order the reference to remain. You may need it in the future.

The code may work with late binding, too, but it should be better to have the benefit of intellisense, i think.

Answer (score 0):

With <kbd>Excel O365</kbd> you can do it by formula (if you wish).

```
=FILTER(A1:A13,COUNTIFS(A1:A13,A1:A13,B1:B13,FALSE)=0)
```

[image]